# Using command line tools from python PYPI packages

Tags: python

this is a newbie question that I couldn't find an answer for, I downloaded a package from python PYPI, I was able to use all the modules in the package, however under documentation I noticed, there were some command line tools, which could be very useful for me, so I was wondering if anyone knew how I could use these tools. 
http://packages.python.org/macholib/scripts.html#macho-find

Comment: How did you download this package? Did you download the .tar.gz file and extract it? If so, did you run python setup.py install? Or did you use something like pip or easy_install? I think you're on the right track, but if we know what you've done, we can easily pick out the steps you've missed.

Comment: yes I did exactly what you said, downloaded the file unzipped it, then ran setup install, I can use the other modules but not these command line tools, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed using the normal `python setup.py install` or with `pip install ...`, you should already find that the scripts are on your path.  For this library, it looks like three are provided:

[setup.cfg](http://download.ag-projects.com/SipClient/python-backports-1.0.0.tar.gz)

```
console_scripts = 
    macho_find = macholib.macho_find:main
    macho_standalone = macholib.macho_standalone:main
    macho_dump = macholib.macho_dump:main
```

Comment: so lets say I want to do macho_find in a folder, I open terminal I cd into that folder and then what do I type in?

Answer (score -1):

The standard way to use a module as a command line tool, is to use the `-m` switch. For example, to use the `timeit` module to time a small section of code:

```
python -m timeit "range(0, 10)"
```

Which then gives:

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.339 usec per loop
```

From `python -h`:

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

Comment: so I tried 

python -m macholib.macho_find

that didn't work either it gave me this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/macholib/macho_find.py", line 14, in <module>
TypeError: main() takes no arguments (1 given)